# The product is not calculated correctly

Tags: c++

[image: pic]

I wrote code to evaluate the expression above. It executes, but I suspect that the expression is not evaluated correctly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    setlocale(0, "");

    // Задание 1
    cout << "Задание 1" << endl;
    cout << "" << endl;

    double m, x, k, k1, k2;
    int n = 18;

    cout << "Определите m: ";
    cin >> m;

    cout << "Определите x: "; // вероятно, в задании ошибка. Если не положу ничего в x - там будет 
                              //единица, ответы будут примерно одинаковые.
    cin >> x;

    do // начало цикла do while
    {
        k2 = pow(x, 3*x+1);
        k1 = k2 * (8*x);
        k = k1 - 785;
    }
    while (n < m); // конец цикла do while

    cout << "Результат вычисления, k = " << k << endl;

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: "*but I suspect that the expression is not evaluated correctly.*" what makes you suspect that? What were you entering as input and what was the actual output vs. the expected output?

Comment: First thing, the `- 785` is outside the product operator, so you shouldn't have it in your loop.

Comment: Also please note that [StackOverflow Russian](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/) exists if you don't want to convert your comments/variable names to English before posting here on the English site.

Comment: Just a guess: doubles are not [100% precise](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/floating-point-numbers/) - depending on how large x is you might run into precision problems

Comment: Please don't post images. Include all relevant information in the question as *text*. Also; if you used English for your text in the code and comments it would be much more approachable for a broader audience.

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: `(n < m)` is the looping condition, yet the body of the loop never modifies `n` nor `m`. This will only loop once or loop forever.

Comment: If the formula is right, it should just be `k = pow(pow(x, 3*x + 1) + 8*x, m - n + 1) - 795;`, without a loop. In your loop, other than the misplaced 795, you also have `k1 = k2 * (8*x);` instead of `k1 = k2 + (8*x);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use a loop instead of calling `std::pow`, you have to fix its condition and iteration expression. The calculations inside the body are also different from the posted formula. Note the following changes:

```
double k = 1.0;
for (int i = n; i <= m; ++i)
{ //        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^     
    k *= pow(x, 3.0 * x + 1.0) + 8.0 * x;
  //  ^^                      ^^^         
}
k -= 785.0;     // <- This should be outside
```

Note that the body of the `for` loop doesn't depend on `i`, so that there are plenty of ways to refactor this code in more efficient ways.